# Cloud Funtions Get download Url from created file

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

The function executes after each upload in a bucket. It converts the upload and uploads it into the bucket then changes the Download Url in an firebase doc.

It works fine when I upload every 10 sec, but behaves strange when I upload every sec.

It writes the url from the **last** upload into the database. This behaviour is consitent, but I cant find the error.

**The Error:**
File gets uploaded -> compressed -> New File Url is saved in DB everything works fine

When i upload 2 Files 1st one Works fine.
The 2nd file is uploaded right also the new compressed files has the right name but has the content of the first file same for all the next uploads till some time pass.

```
export const smallermemes = functions.storage.bucket('memelyuserkawaiuploads')
.object()
.onFinalize(async (object: ObjectMetadata) => {
console.log('starting exe smallermemes');
if (object) {
  const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
  const filePath = object.name || "";
  const filePathArray = filePath.split('/')
  const fileName = filePathArray.pop() || "";
  const fileDir = filePathArray[0] || "";

  const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);
  const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'compress');

  const tmpFilePath = join(workingDir, 'source.png');

  if (fileName.includes('compress@') || !object.contentType || !object.contentType.includes('image') || !fileDir.includes("uploads")) {
    console.log('exiting function smallermemes');
    return false;
  }

  // 1. Ensure thumbnail dir exists
  await fs.ensureDir(workingDir);

  // 2. Download Source File
  await bucket.file(filePath).download({
    destination: tmpFilePath
  });

  // 3. Resize the images and define an array of upload promises
  const thumbName = path.parse(`compress@_${fileName}`).name + '.webp';


  const thumbPath = join(workingDir, thumbName);

  // Resize source image
  await sharp(tmpFilePath)
    .webp({ quality: 75 })
    .toFile(thumbPath);

  // Upload to GCS
  await bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
    destination: join(bucketDir, thumbName)
  });

  const thumbFile = await bucket.file(join(bucketDir, thumbName));
  const config = {
    action: 'read',
    expires: '03-01-2500',
  };
  const [thumbFileUrl] = await thumbFile.getSignedUrl(config);

  await admin.firestore().collection('uploadsCollection').doc(fileName).update({ DownloadUrl: thumbFileUrl });
  console.log("fileName: " + fileName);
  console.log("thumbName: " + thumbName);
  // 5. Cleanup remove the tmp/compress from the filesystem
  return fs.remove(workingDir);
}
return false;
});
```

i gues the mistake is in the getSignedUrl call but i was following the docs at
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.5.x/File#getSignedUrl

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "behaves strange"?  What doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: If I upload an image while the function is not terminated from the last call, I get a the Url of the previous image, but the fileName and thumbName are correct in the logs.

Comment: Could you edit the question to describe more clearly the exact sequence of events that leads to the unexpected behavior?  Please be specific about the paths of the files you're uploading, and what you expect the happen after everything completes.

Comment: The Error is definitly in this pice of code
await sharp(tmpFilePath)
        .webp({ quality: 75 })
        .toFile(thumbPath);
replacing it with await fs.createReadStream(tmpFilePath).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(thumbPath)); make it work

Comment: Apart, you can upload a file and generate a signed url in parallel, these actions dont have to run sequentially

Answer (score 0):

Turn out sharp has some sort of internal cache

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1848
https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/api-utility/#cache

disabling it solved my problem